RegEx: different results in sandbox and browser
I have an email validation regex, it goes like this ^(?:[\w-]+\.?)+@(?:[\w-]+\.?)+[\w-]\.[a-z]{2,}$
I checked it in a couple of sandboxes and it works as intended. However when I run my code (a simple html form + a bit of css) in a browser (via Live Server or GH pages) it behaves differently. I can put there something like g^&@h and it displays as a valid email. What could be the issue? The corresponding bit of code:
<div class="form__field">
                        <input class="form__input" type="email" name="email" pattern="^(?:[\w-]+\.?)+@(?:[\w-]+\.?)+[\w-]\.[a-z]{2,}$" placeholder="E-Mail" required />
                        <span class="form__error">Example: my-mail@mail.com</span>
                    </div>

full code: https://github.com/glpsch/RegExp-exercise
I tried different browsers, the behaviour is the same.

A literal - must be escaped in a character class in an HTML/JavaScript regex according to the MDN documentation:

In addition to ] and \, the following characters must be escaped in
character classes if they represent literal characters: (, ), [, {, },
/, -, |. This list is somewhat similar to the list of syntax
characters, except that ^, $, *, +, and ? are not reserved inside
character classes, while / and - are not reserved outside character
classes (although / may delimit a regex literal and therefore still
needs to be escaped).

You also don't need to anchor your regex with ^ and $ since the browser does it for you, so the following regex would work:
(?:[\w\-]+\.?)+@(?:[\w\-]+\.?)+[\w\-]\.[a-z]{2,}

Demo:


@keyframes errors {
    from {
      margin-top: -5px;
      opacity: .1; 
    }
  
    to {
      margin-top: 10px;
      opacity: 1;
    }
}

html {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}

.header {
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
    width: 150px;
}

.header__logo-sub {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

.form {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}

.block {
    margin-top: 60px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

.cover {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

.cover__image {
    width: 110px;
    min-width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    background-image: url(regex.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
  
.cover__heading {
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    line-height: 1;
}

.form__field {
    margin-bottom: 36px;
}

.form__fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.form__error {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #df4b41;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    animation: errors .1s ease-in-out;
}

.form__input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.form__button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ffdb4d;
    color: #000;
}

.form__input:valid:not(:placeholder-shown) {
    border-color: #ffdb4d;
}

.form__input:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) {
    border-color: #df4b41;
}

.form__input:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) + .form__error {
    display: block;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Regular Expressions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <p class="header__logo-sub">Regular expressions</p>
    </header>
    <main class="container">
        <div class="cover">
            <div class="cover__image"></div>
            <h1 class="cover__heading">RegExp</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <form class="form" name="register">
                <h3>Registration form</h3>
                <fieldset class="form__fieldset">
                    <div class="form__field">                        
                        <input class="form__input" type="text" name="name" pattern="(^[А-Я][а-яё]*(-[А-Я][а-яё]*)?$)|(^[A-Z][a-z]*(-[A-Z][a-z]*)?$)" placeholder="Name / Имя" minlength="2" maxlength="20" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form__field">
                        <input class="form__input" type="email" name="email" pattern="(?:[\w\-]+\.?)+@(?:[\w\-]+\.?)+[\w\-]\.[a-z]{2,}" placeholder="E-Mail" required />
                        <span class="form__error">Example: my-mail@example.com</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form__field">
                        <input class="form__input" type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Telephone number" pattern="^\+?\d{1,3}\s?\(?\d{3}\)?\s?-?\d{3}\s?-?(?:\d{2}\s?-?)\d{2}$" minlength="11" maxlength="20"  required/>
                        <span class="form__error">Example: +7 (900) 000-00-00 or +79000000000</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form__field">
                        <input class="form__input" type="url" name="url" pattern="^(?:(https:\/\/)|(http:\/\/))(?:((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})|((?:www\.)?(?:\w+\.?)+\w+))(?::[1-9]\d{1,4})?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?)*#?$" placeholder="Your website" required/>
                        <span class="form__error">Example: http://example.com</span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="form__button" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>  
   
</body>
</html>



